# JQuery's click event on canvas - looks ugly on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, canvas

I want to create HTML/Javascript drawing application for iPad , using HTML5 canvas. Canvas has jQuery click listener.

When canvas is clicked, it turns gray for a moment. As I understand, in Ipad, this is standard behaviour for clickable elements in web pages.

Is it possible to avoid such gray flickering, since it is very disturbing. Or is there any other way to catch click event on canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`-webkit-tap-highlight-color`](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-tap-highlight-color) to fully transparent for the canvas element. For example:

```
canvas {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```